# Polidea/ios-class-guard - Error with installed libraries

Tags: ios, objective-c, obfuscation

We are using Infragistics grid in our project by installing the library (.dmg), library header files in "/Developer" path.
When obfuscate the project we got this error:

```
TTouchGridView.h:9:9: fatal error: 
'IG/IG.h' file not found
#import <IG/IG.h>
```

*Xcode 7.1.1

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the frameworks in quotes?  "/Developer/Infragistics/NUCLiOS 2015 Volume 2/Framework".  This suggestion is from this forum thread: http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/p/103039/489956.aspx#489956

Comment: Did you exclude `Infragistics` library from obfuscation? You should use `-i <symbol>` parameter to ignore external libraries which cannot be obfuscated.

Comment: @psci
How to exclude Infragistics library ?
I am trying like this
CLASS_GUARD_OPTS="-i '!IG*' -i '!UISS'"
but still iOS class guard obfuscating it 
2016-01-10 11:47:54.693 ios-class-guard[71726:1372666] Obfuscating @ class IGAxis
2016-01-10 11:47:54.694 ios-class-guard[71726:1372666] Obfuscating @ class IGCategoryAxisBase
2016-01-10 11:47:54.694 ios-class-guard[71726:1372666] Obfuscating @ class IGNumericAxisBase

Answer (score 0):

Remove your frameworks IG and IGChart from Xcode Project.Add Manually from /Developer/Infragistics/NUCLiOS 2015 Volume 2/Framework folder or drag and drop both frameworks from same folder to xCode project.

Then try to clean and super clean , Now Compile the Source it will work